# Run psql query using ssh

Tags: ssh, psql, remote-server

I wrote a file.sh to execute psql query from remote sever. I'm stuck on the first step:

```
ssh user@myserver.com "psql database"
```

=> Nothing happens

I tried several different syntaxes that I found on google, but nothing works for me.

Manualy I process like this without problem:

```
$ ssh myserver
$ psql database
database=> select foo from table;
```

I don't know what I missed (it's my first bash script)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the entire script, and/or show how the actual query is supposed to be input into the psql program.

Answer (score -1):

I use SSH every day to connect to my work server and use `ssh user@server`. From there, I am able to run files, connect to my database, etc.